# MahApps ToggleSwitch customize - 'KnobTranslateTransform' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.Border'

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro, blend

I would customize the ToggleSwitch from MahApps. For that I made a project and opened it with the Visual Blend 2019.
I simply done:

1. Right Click on the ToggleSwitch.
2. Select "Edit Template"
3. Select "Edit Copy"

Sadly I'm getting : "'KnobTranslateTransform' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.Border'."

**Do I missing some Reference? Or do I have to set the KnobTranslateTransform with some additional stuff?**

Thanks for any help.

This are my references:
[Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uQ1y.png)

This is my xaml file:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ToggleAirCustomSwitch"
        xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" x:Class="ToggleAirCustomSwitch.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ToggleSwitchAirStyle" TargetType="{x:Type mah:ToggleSwitch}">
            <Setter Property="ContentDirection" Value="RightToLeft"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Fonts.Family.ToggleSwitch}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Font.Size.ToggleSwitch}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.ContentForeground}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type mah:ToggleSwitch}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding mah:ControlsHelper.CornerRadius}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ToggleStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition From="Dragging" GeneratedDuration="0" GeneratedEasingFunction="{x:Null}" To="On">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="KnobTranslateTransform">
                                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="24">
                                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                            <ExponentialEase Exponent="9"/>
                                                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds">
                                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder">
                                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOn">
                                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOff">
                                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualTransition>
                                        <VisualTransition From="Dragging" GeneratedDuration="0" GeneratedEasingFunction="{x:Null}" To="Off">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="KnobTranslateTransform">
                                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0">
                                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                            <ExponentialEase Exponent="9"/>
                                                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualTransition>
                                        <VisualTransition From="On" GeneratedDuration="0" GeneratedEasingFunction="{x:Null}" To="Off">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="KnobTranslateTransform">
                                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0">
                                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                            <ExponentialEase Exponent="9"/>
                                                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualTransition>
                                        <VisualTransition From="Off" GeneratedDuration="0" GeneratedEasingFunction="{x:Null}" To="On">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="KnobTranslateTransform">
                                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="24">
                                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                            <ExponentialEase Exponent="9"/>
                                                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds">
                                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder">
                                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOn">
                                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOff">
                                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualTransition>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Dragging"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Off">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="KnobTranslateTransform"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="On">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="24" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="KnobTranslateTransform"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds">
                                                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder">
                                                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOn">
                                                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOff">
                                                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ContentStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="OffContent">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="OffContentPresenter"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="OffContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="OnContent">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="OnContentPresenter"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="OnContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.HeaderForeground}" TextElement.FontWeight="{TemplateBinding mah:HeaderedControlHelper.HeaderFontWeight}" TextElement.FontStretch="{TemplateBinding mah:HeaderedControlHelper.HeaderFontStretch}" TextElement.FontSize="{TemplateBinding mah:HeaderedControlHelper.HeaderFontSize}" TextElement.FontFamily="{TemplateBinding mah:HeaderedControlHelper.HeaderFontFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding mah:HeaderedControlHelper.HeaderHorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding mah:HeaderedControlHelper.HeaderMargin}" Grid.Row="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding mah:HeaderedControlHelper.HeaderVerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="{DynamicResource ToggleSwitchThemeMinWidth}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{DynamicResource ToggleSwitchContentSpaceMargin}"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="{DynamicResource ToggleSwitchPreContentMargin}"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="{DynamicResource ToggleSwitchPostContentMargin}"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid x:Name="SwitchAreaGrid" Background="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.ContainerBackground}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,5" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="OffContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding OffContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding OffContent}" Grid.Column="2" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding OffContentStringFormat}" TextElement.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" TextElement.FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" TextElement.FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding ContentPadding}" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="OnContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding OnContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding OnContent}" Grid.Column="2" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding OnContentStringFormat}" TextElement.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" TextElement.FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" TextElement.FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding ContentPadding}" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="2" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" TextElement.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" TextElement.FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" TextElement.FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding ContentPadding}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                    <Grid x:Name="Switch" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Grid.Row="1" Width="44">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="OuterBorder" Fill="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.FillOff}" RadiusY="10" RadiusX="10" Stroke="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.StrokeOff}" StrokeThickness="{DynamicResource ToggleSwitchOffStrokeThickness}"/>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="SwitchKnobBounds" Fill="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.FillOn}" Opacity="0" RadiusY="10" RadiusX="10" Stroke="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.StrokeOn}" StrokeThickness="{DynamicResource ToggleSwitchOnStrokeThickness}"/>
                                        <Grid x:Name="SwitchKnob" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Width="20">
                                            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                                <TranslateTransform/>
                                            </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                            <Ellipse x:Name="SwitchKnobOn" Fill="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.KnobFillOn}" Height="10" Opacity="0" Width="10"/>
                                            <Ellipse x:Name="SwitchKnobOff" Fill="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.KnobFillOff}" Height="10" Width="10"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Thumb x:Name="SwitchThumb" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                                        <Thumb.Template>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                                <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Thumb.Template>
                                    </Thumb>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="ContentDirection" Value="LeftToRight">
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="ContentPresenter" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="OffContentPresenter" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="OnContentPresenter" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="Switch" Value="2"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.FillOffPointerOver}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.StrokeOffPointerOver}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="SwitchAreaGrid" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.ContainerBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.FillOnPointerOver}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.StrokeOnPointerOver}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="SwitchKnobOff" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.KnobFillOffPointerOver}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="SwitchKnobOn" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.KnobFillOnPointerOver}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.FillOffPressed}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.StrokeOffPressed}"/>
                                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="SwitchAreaGrid" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.ContainerBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.FillOnPressed}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.StrokeOnPressed}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="SwitchKnobOff" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.KnobFillOffPressed}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="SwitchKnobOn" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.KnobFillOnPressed}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="ContentPresenter" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.ContentForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.HeaderForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="OffContentPresenter" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.ContentForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="OnContentPresenter" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.ContentForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.FillOffDisabled}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.StrokeOffDisabled}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="SwitchAreaGrid" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.ContainerBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.FillOnDisabled}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.StrokeOnDisabled}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="SwitchKnobOff" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.KnobFillOffDisabled}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="SwitchKnobOn" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ToggleSwitch.KnobFillOnDisabled}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Templates.ValidationError}"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="mah:HeaderedControlHelper.HeaderFontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Fonts.Family.ToggleSwitch.Header}"/>
            <Setter Property="mah:HeaderedControlHelper.HeaderFontSize" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Font.Size.ToggleSwitch.Header}"/>
            <Setter Property="mah:HeaderedControlHelper.HeaderMargin" Value="{DynamicResource ToggleSwitchTopHeaderMargin}"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <mah:ToggleSwitch x:Name="RibbAirOnOff_ToggleSwitch"
                          IsOn="{Binding ToggleSwitchAirIsChecked}"
                          IsEnabled="{Binding ToggleSwitchAirIsEnabled, Mode=OneWay}"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                          OnCommand="{Binding AirOnCommand}"
                          OffCommand="{Binding AirOffCommand}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Style="{DynamicResource ToggleSwitchAirStyle}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style was not properly extracted by Blend. In the following line, the assignment of the name `x:Name="KnobTranslateTransform"` is missing, so the element has no name and cannot be found.

```
<Grid.RenderTransform>
   <TranslateTransform x:Name="KnobTranslateTransform" />
</Grid.RenderTransform>
```

It should look like this instead:

```
<Grid.RenderTransform>
   <TranslateTransform x:Name="KnobTranslateTransform"/>
</Grid.RenderTransform>
```

I suppose that there could be other errors in the style and template. I recommend you to copy the style directly from the GitHub repository, as Blend does not seem to be reliable here. The style for `ToggleSwitch` can be found [here](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/Themes/ToggleSwitch.xaml).

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I'm looking for.